# R - extract submatrix with column name

Tags: r

R - is there any way to extract multiple column from a matrix with column names?
for example in matrix below:

```
 
  A B C D  E
A 1 3 5 7  9
B 2 4 6 8 10
```

extract submatrix with column C, D and E, like:

```
 
  C D  E
A 5 7  9
B 6 8 10
```

thanks.

Comment: M <- matrix(1:10, nrow = 2, dimnames = list(LETTERS[1:2], LETTERS[1:5])) and then subset like this M[ , c("C", "D", "E")]....very basic you should read and introduction book about R

Answer (score 4):

As long as the matrix has column names (returned by `colnames(m)`) you can use them to index the columns you'd like to extract.

```
m[, c("C", "D", "E")]
#   C D  E
# A 5 7  9
# B 6 8 10
```

Comment: thanks, an other way is using, subset, for example: subset(m, select = c("C", "D", "E"))

Comment: `subset()` is nice for interactive use, but the way I've shown you is *generally* better. (See the **Warning:** section of the `?subset` help file for a note about why.)